# How to get a value from a table which is not inserted for the day?

Tags: sql, oracle, report

Let's say I have a SQL table in Oracle where the commission of the agents is stored each day. So if agent A makes a commission of 25 it goes to the table with a date, but if he doesn't get anything that day nothing goes to the table. Now suppose I have four agents (A,B,C,D), how can I generate a report where commission earned by an agent is shown based on specific date, and if he doesn't earn anything that day 'Absent' is shown next to his name.

Actual table looks like this:

```
SELECT Agent_name Comm Date
FROM AGENT_COMM_TAB 
WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE, 'DD-MM-YYYY') LIKE '15-04-2017';

Agent_name Comm Date
A          23   15-04-2017
C          20   15-04-2017
D          19   15-04-2017
```

Report should look like this:

```
Agent Comm
A     23
B     Absent
C     20
D     19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me assume you have a table of agents.  Then you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.Agent_name, act.Comm, act.Date
FROM AGENTS a LEFT JOIN
     AGENT_COMM_TAB act
     ON a.? = act.?
WHERE act.DATE >= DATE '2017-04-15' AND
      act.DATE < DATE '2017-04-16';
```

If `Comm` is a *string*, then you can get "absent" by using `COALESCE()`:  `COALESCE(act.comm, 'absent')`.  However, a `NULL` value should be sufficient.

Also, I don't know what the right `JOIN` condition would be.  If you don't have a table of agents, you can generate on in the query:

```
SELECT a.Agent_name, act.Comm, act.Date
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Agent_Name FROM AGENT_COMM_TAB) a LEFT JOIN
     AGENT_COMM_TAB act
     ON a.Agent_name = act.Agent_name
WHERE act.DATE >= DATE '2017-04-15' AND
      act.DATE < DATE '2017-04-16';
```